# Marker Clusterer overlapping MarkerWithLabel's label

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker, markerclusterer

I'm using markerWithLabel for my individual markers and markerclusterer for my clusters.

What happens is when my marker's label is oppened it's 'z-index' seems lower than the clusterer, but I can't alter these settings.. 
I've seen something about different panes in a map, but I coudn't figure out how to do this.

This is the website I'm working on.

I have made this example. 
UPDATED: http://jsfiddle.net/n5npnchp/39/

```js
function magic() //it's where the magic happens
```

I have increased my label's height just to show what I'm talking about. 
If you click the 8 markers cluster and then hover the marker near 'Parque Florestal'(Green Area)
You can see that the black label stands above the clusterer.. I can change it..

I don't know remember why this project is using marker with label, not infoWindow, is this the best to do in this case?

Comment: Make a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that (or at least the parts you find relevant).

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip, I changed it a lot, but I think it's still too big.. I'll keep checking if I can reduce it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's the best solution but I changed the markerwithlabel.js file

```js
 //this.getPanes().overlayImage.appendChild(this.labelDiv_); THIS
  this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.labelDiv_); //TO THIS

 //this.getPanes().overlayImage.appendChild(this.crossDiv_); AND THIS
    this.getPanes().overlayImage.appendChild(this.crossDiv_); //TO THIS
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check [Here](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Fixed%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=24)

I hope this will help you.